# How to connect aws instance with aws cli?

Tags: linux, ssh, amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I don't have ssh key but I have access to aws portal and console where the ec2 machine is there.

I tried using the steps in this [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-connect-methods.html) to connect ec2 instance.

Method 1:

using only instance-id and mssh

```
mssh i-038317982dc6a7c64
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(mssh:2876): Gtk-WARNING **: 14:03:20.071: cannot open display:
```

Method 2:
To generate a new ssh key and push that to ec2 instance.

```
aws ec2-instance-connect send-ssh-public-key     --instance-id i-038317982dc6a7c64     --availability-zone us-east-1b    --instance-os-user ec2-user     --ssh-public-key file://my_key.pub

An error occurred (EC2InstanceNotFoundException) when calling the SendSSHPublicKey operation: Instance not found.
```

But that machine is there.

So I tried by providing region also.

```
aws ec2-instance-connect send-ssh-public-key     --instance-id i-038317982dc6a7c64     --availability-zone us-east-1b --region us-east-1    --instance-os-user ec2-user     --ssh-public-key file://my_key.pub
{
    "RequestId": "9ecd1748-1ef3-4b7b-b1a5-5ae4370df452",
    "Success": true
}
```

Then, I tried connecting with ssh.

But with dns name or ip address, I am getting permission denied only.

```
ssh -o "IdentitiesOnly=yes" -i my_key ec2-user@54.174.85.61
The authenticity of host '54.174.85.61 (54.174.85.61)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:7hTrm5wLeicqFVbNG9MW7HDEqUZQDi/H/OzJ3AwL0zU.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? yes
Warning: Permanently added '54.174.85.61' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
ec2-user@54.174.85.61: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).



ssh -o "IdentitiesOnly=yes" -i my_key ec2-user@ec2-54-174-85-61.compute-1.amazonaws.com
    The authenticity of host 'ec2-54-174-85-61.compute-1.amazonaws.com (54.174.85.61)' can't be established.
    ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:7hTrm5wLeicqFVbNG9MW7HDEqUZQDi/H/OzJ3AwL0zU.
    Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? yes
    Warning: Permanently added 'ec2-54-174-85-61.compute-1.amazonaws.com' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
    ec2-user@ec2-54-174-85-61.compute-1.amazonaws.com: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

Please suggest what are the options available to connect aws linux 2 machine with aws credentials configured in the console and having instanceid/machine dns name or ip address